# 72/72 = .0001572 - Yikes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting an incorrect number when I divide two ints. Here's my code:

```
SELECT self_cert_pct_certified_vw.regn_bu,
   sum (self_cert_pct_certified_vw.certified) AS certified,
   sum (self_cert_pct_certified_vw.not_certified) AS not_certified,
   (sum (certified) * 1.0) AS numerator,

   (SELECT sum (certified) + sum (not_certified)) AS denomonator,
     (sum (certified))
   / CAST (
        (SELECT sum (certified) + sum (not_certified)
           FROM self_cert_pct_certified_vw) AS FLOAT)
   * 100.0

   AS pct_certified
FROM self_cert_pct_certified_vw
WHERE ( (     time_period = '2'
      AND self_cert_pct_certified_vw.regn_id = 'DCT'
      AND (certified > 0 OR not_certified > 0)))
GROUP BY self_cert_pct_certified_vw.regn_bu
ORDER BY self_cert_pct_certified_vw.regn_bu
```

Here is an example of one of the results I am getting:

```
regn_bu certified   not_certified   numerator   denomonator     pct_certified
DCT_CL  72        0                 72.0             72         0.0157270483388305
```

Both 'certified' and 'not_certified' are declared as int. I expected the answer to be 100 percent not 0.015... !

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: int/float * float  =  float try casting numerator and denominator and multiplier to int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing apples and oranges.  Why are you doing a subquery again for the ratio?

Instead, just use the values:

```
SELECT self_cert_pct_certified_vw.regn_bu,
       sum(self_cert_pct_certified_vw.certified) AS certified,
       sum(self_cert_pct_certified_vw.not_certified) AS not_certified,
       (sum(certified) * 1.0) AS numerator,

       (sum(certified) + sum(not_certified)) AS denomonator,
       (sum(certified) * 1.0) / (sum(certified) + sum(not_certified)) * 100 as pct_certified
    . . .
```

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the calculations in the `from` clause in the aggregation subquery.  However, I cannot fully explain the issue, unless you have a `where` or `group by` clause not shown in the question.

EDIT:

Well, the completed code explains the problem.  The ratio you want is within a group.  The ratio you are calculated has the total number overall all records due to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting all `INT` columns to float by multiplying by `1e0`. Dividing two integer values (columns) yields an integer. Multiplying by 1.0 will yield decimals, not floats.

Comment: Casted all columns to float by multiplying by 1e0 and still received the same results.